# Stored procedure support in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: stored-procedures, functions, mysql-workbench

I've created a lot of stored procedures when I was using HeidiSQL on Windows.  I am now on an iMAC (x64) and it doesn't look like installing HeidiSQL is an option.

I've got MySQL Workbench version 8.0.24, it does list the stored procedures and functions but I cannot edit these in the application.

I'm surprised that this functionality appears to be missing or disabled.  Has anyone got a suggestions?  Tools that will work on iMAC (x64):

```
macOS Big Sur
Version 11.3.1
iMAC (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
Processor 4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
Memory 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
```

Comment: MySQL Workbench has long been ... underwhelming and messy. I use Sequel Pro and/or TablePlus when trying to get work done. [Sequel Pro](https://sequelpro.com/download) is free. [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com) has a trial and is available for a fair price ... and works with multiple database engines.

Comment: @matigo, Thank you downloading Sequel Pro will give it a go.

Comment: @matigo, ok, downloaded and run, if I click a function or procedure, it creates a tab showing the name but that is all, there is no content displayed to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  workbench you find all to stored procedures, when you make a right cick on stored procedures.

In your case use Alter Stored procedures

It is basically all the same for view tables columns etc.

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote: these object editors (table editor, sp editor, trigger editor etc.) are designed to allow only the specific part of the language for which they are configured. This way you don't need any `DELIMITER` command in the code, nor can you write anything that doesn't match the current object type (it will all be reported as syntax errors).